# Catch a psql(PostgreSQL) command error in bash, that can be used generic, indifferent of the sql

Tags: bash, postgresql, postgresql-10

I want to catch a PostgreSQL error in bash.

For example:

```
function create_database:
    sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE DATABASE $1 WITH OWNER $2;"
```

I want something that can catch any type of postgres errors (not only for create) and `echo` the error

also in case of error `return 1`

If I use:
 `$RESULT=$(sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE DATABASE $1 WITH OWNER $2;")`

I get the answer from `psql` but is specific to the operation, so I have to do string matching for each SQL command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fairly trivial to see if the statement was successful or not: just check the return code.

```bash
$ sudo -u postgres psql -c 'melect 32'
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "melect"
LINE 1: melect 32
        ^
$ echo $?
1

$ sudo -u postgres psql -c 'DROP TABLE not_exists'
ERROR:  table "not_exists" does not exist
$ echo $?
1

$ sudo -u postgres psql -c 'SELECT 42'
 ?column? 
----------
       42
(1 row)

$ echo $?
0
```

So your code could do something like this:

```bash
sudo -u postgres psql -c "..." >/tmp/result 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo /tmp/result >>logfile
    rm -f /tmp/result
    exit 1
else
    rm -f /tmp/result
fi
```

Comment: thanks, &>2 doesn't catch the psql answer, psql will still show the result itself(failure or not) and &>2 doesn't output anything

Comment: Oh, I missed that you want the output of the command. I have modified the answer.